# How to access connected app using AJAX tool kit

Tags: connected-apps, ajax

We have different communities in our org, for ex: community1, community2 etc. We have a connected app created in the org. the IdP-Initiated Login URL will be different for different communities. We need to get these links in VF page depending on the login user. I found that this is not possible using apex but with AJAX tool it is possible. So can anyone please let me know how can we use AJAX tool kit to get these urls in VF page?

Thank you,
NHK